# How can I write this SQL query correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to write a query to get the right results.

I'll keep it simple. First, the foundation:

I have two tables: `DEALS` and `TASKS`
A Deal can have 1 or more Task inside, so `TASKS` has a `deal_id` field.

Also, every Task has a `time_start` field (unix timestamp) and a `completed` field (1 or 0).

Ok. Now, what I need? In my view I need to show all deals with the "Next Task" column rendered.

So for every Deal, if I have a Task (one or more) it must show only the closest. If no Task, I'll render an alert.

```
Deal Title | Value | Next step
deal 1     | 1.000 | tomorrow at 11:00
deal 2     | 1.000 | NO TASK IN THIS DEAL
deal 3     | 1.500 | 12/03/2017 at 9:00
```

In this example, deal 1 has 3 tasks inside, but the nearest start tomorrow. I don't want "deal 1" repeated 3 times. <-- `GROUP BY deals.id`??

To get this right, currently, I run the deals query without JOIN and I'm using a custom PDO class to run a new query for tasks for every row.
But this is BAD! I have a new query for every row of the `DEALS` table.

I'm pretty sure that there is a way to write one single query to get this result.

PS: Don't care about the rendering of the text, I used "tomorrow" only to write the example, `next_spet` is the unix timestamp from the db ... I can easily use `moment.js` to format it correctly.

EDIT:
I'll provide the data inside the 2 tables, just to complete the example.

```
DEALS
ID | TITLE   | VALUE  
1  | Deal 1  | 1000  
2  | Deal 2  | 1000  
3  | Deal 3  | 1000  

TASKS
ID | DEAL_ID | TITLE              | TIME_START | COMPLETED  
1  |    1    | Send Proposal      | 1483678800 | 0  
2  |    1    | Follow up          | 1483441200 | 0  
3  |    1    | Ask for referrals  | 1484441200 | 0  
4  |    2    | Send email         | 1483678900 | 0  
5  |    3    | Sort out meeting   | 1483678900 | 0
```

NOTE: timestamps don't match with the results that I have written in the first table. They were just an example, I take the timestamp of the `time_start` field and format it in a human readable mode, but this isn't my question.

Comment: you show us expected results but you don't show us the data in the table.  You need show the data in the two tables that produces that result.

Comment: I've just add some data.

Comment: Looks to me like your data does not match your expected results.  Why does deal 2 not have send email in the results, why are the results not showing any of the listed tasks?  Can you please have your expected results match your example data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```
select 
    d.title as 'Deal Title',
    d.value as 'Value',
    IsNull(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), min(t.time_start)), 'NO TASK IN THIS DEAL') as 'Next step'
from Deals d
left join Tasks t
    on t.deal_id = d.deal_id
    and t.is_completed = 0
    and t.time_start > GetDate()
group by d.deal_id, d.title, d.value
```

Here's the SQLite equivalent:

```
select 
    d.title as 'Deal Title',
    d.value as 'Value',
    IfNull(min(t.time_start), 'NO TASK IN THIS DEAL') as 'Next step'
from Deals d
left join Tasks t
    on t.deal_id = d.deal_id
    and t.is_completed = 0
    and t.time_start > now()  --remove this line to include past Tasks
group by d.deal_id, d.title, d.value
```

Comment: This seems wrong, the current date and time should have no bearing on results -- but getting only one report what is important.

Comment: Not according to jacopo's comment above.  The grouping conditions give you one line per Deal, with the next incomplete future Task, as specified in the original question.

Comment: Interesting -- I took that as English being a second language -- not meaning "Future" but instead meaning "Next" or "After".

Comment: The point of view is the Deal. It has one or more task. I need the first incomplete one. If there are 2 tasks, one set for yesterday, one for today, both incomplete, I need the first incomplete, so the one set for yesterday.

Comment: I tried your SQLite example ... It works! I was struggling with the AND condition inside the JOIN. It's the first time that I see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the time of the next task, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select d.*,
       (select t.time_start
        from tasks t
        where t.deal_id = d.deal_id and t.time_start > d.time_col
        order by t.time_start
        limit 1
       ) as task_time_start
from deals d;
```

EDIT:

If you want the future, then just change the time comparison:

```
select d.*,
       (select t.time_start
        from tasks t
        where t.deal_id = d.deal_id and t.completed = 0 and
              t.time_start > now()
        order by t.time_start
        limit 1
       ) as task_time_start
from deals d;
```

Comment: I think he just wants the min time that is not completed not the next one from a non-specified column in deals.

Comment: @Hogan correct. In the result list I just want to show the nearest task (associated to its deal) in the future that is not completed yet.

Comment: @jacopo.galli -- just to clarify when you say "future" here do you mean future of the person running the report of "after" the prior task?

Comment: The First incomplete task. It's not a "future" of the person. Indeed, it's should be an overdue task.